# Keeping "chat" windows on a lateral

Tags: awesome-wm

I use awesome for quite a while at home, but when setting it up at work I'm facing an issue. I need to keep an eye on 2 chat windows where I'm usually just watching people talk.
I created 2 "google-chrome --app=http://uol" windows, so they open nicely not using much space (ie, like an app).

Since I mostly work with a browser and/or a terminal, the behavior I think would be interesting would probably involve having a single tab with "chat windows on 20% of the screen" and "browser and/or terminal sharing the rest of the screen".

I tried to do something similar to that using tabs, but it doesn't work well (focus issues when switching tabs, and hard to use browser AND terminal (like when I'm following a tutorial on a site and typing on the terminal)).

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can accomplish that or something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I fully understand your question. But, I guess you're looking for what makes the essence of awesome WM: tiling !

On the screenshot below, you see a 'term' tag defined with something like this:

```
awful.tag.add("term", {
                      layout             = awful.layout.suit.tile.left,      
                      screen             = s,
                      selected           = true,
                      gap                = 5,
                      gap_single_client  = true
     })
```

inside the `awful.screen.connect_for_each_screen` command.

IMHO, you can perform what you want using this and rules for your windows to be in that tag.

I hope it will help.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I actually wanted this 2 windows to be shown on the lateral of the first 2 tags, and not others. I ended up accomplishing that by creating an empty 400px widget and attaching those window floating on the left sticky. Then I check for events to control its behavior. When tab changes, if it's not the first/second tab, it will hide the 400px widget and unsticky the windows :)